# XY Coordinates result in weird scale

Tags: coordinates, xy

Currently trying to display XY data with what I consider unusual coordinates. These coordinates come from a transit scheduling software called HASTUS. Though I'm able to plot the points in relation to one another it's at a scale of 1:85,222,723,064

Here are a couple of the coordinates from the spreadsheet I was given:

```
6283072, 1841579
6283413, 1841599
```

These points are for San Diego where coordinates are around

```
32.729849, -117.147729
```

Right now my GCS is WGS 1984 which has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

San Diego is in the State Plane California Zone VI (6) zone, and the coordinates are in US survey feet. The false easting and false northing values for that zone are 6561666.6667 and 1640416.6667. The false easting/northing values are often excellent indications of what coordinates should look like for that projected coordinate reference system (CRS).

A question remains about what geographic CRS (aka datum) was used. It's definitely NAD83, but there have been several re-adjustments/realizations: CORS96, HARN, NSRS2007, 2011. Try using 2011 (if available).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! And your answer has really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

These are (most probably) NAD83 [California State Plane](http://www.conservation.ca.gov/cgs/information/geologic_mapping/state_plane/PublishingImages/zone6.gif) Zone 6 with feet units.

I'm attaching a screenshot from QGIS so you can see the EPSG code

[image]

**EDIT**: and as mkennedy said, perhaps one of the adjustments.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I've been so used to using WGS and it didn't even occur to me to try something different.